# moc (Console audio Player) produces no sound (but no errors either)

Tags: sound, alsa

mocp produces no sound while playing a musicfile. Volume is at 100% and sounds works perfectly in other applications. I setting the ALSA device to a different value but I'm unable to produce sound with moc. I adjusted my configuration file in ~/.moc:

```
SoundDriver = ALSA
ALSADevice = default
ALSAMixer1 = PCM
ALSAMixer2 = Master
```

My idea is that I need to selected a different ALSA device, but i'm not doing that in the correct way. Is there a way to test the different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the alsa device i should have been using. I explicitly need to set the alsa server to: `sysdefault` instead of `default`.